# Where to get the project_id value for a folder in Vimeo?

Tags: vimeo

I'm currently using the API to return the folders from the url path: [https://api.vimeo.com/users/{user_id}/projects](https://api.vimeo.com/users/%7Buser_id%7D/projects)

However the response does not include the project id for the folder. I would like to query the videos in a specific folder using the endpoint:

[https://api.vimeo.com/me/projects/{project_id}/videos](https://api.vimeo.com/me/projects/%7Bproject_id%7D/videos) but I cannot find anywhere the project id value?

Where can I find the project_id value for a folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. I noticed that the [endpoint](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/folders#get_projects) of /me/projects returns all the folders that have the user. You can take the URI of the folder and split it to get only the id. I hope that you find it useful.

Comment: yes, you're right. You would have thought there would be an ID property to use!